# JUnit runner gets NullPointerException from java.io.Writer

Tags: java, junit, surefire

I'm getting a NullPointerException from Maven Surefire plugin. It occurs only on a test that is using DBUnit. The Surefire report file is empty.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireExecutionException: null; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.newLine(PrintWriter.java:436)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:585)
    at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:696)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.AbstractFileReporter.testSetStarting(AbstractFileReporter.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.report.ReporterManager.testSetStarting(ReporterManager.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:127)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:177)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:338)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:997)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.
```

When I try to run the same test from NetBeans IDE using a JUnit runner, I get the same exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.util.DOMElementWriter.write(DOMElementWriter.java:212)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.XMLJUnitResultFormatter.endTestSuite(XMLJUnitResultFormatter.java:171)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.fireEndTestSuite(JUnitTestRunner.java:714)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:547)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1031)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:888)
Test football.dao.jpa.SimpleJPATest FAILED (crashed)
```

The *write* method from java.io.Writer class has only one String parameter. That means the runner must be passing null as an argument. But how does this happen?

```
public void write(String str) throws IOException {
    write(str, 0, str.length());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What youre actually seeing is the line.separator System's property is null.  I cannot explain why based on what I see but if you can test it try doing:

```
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(
               new sun.security.action.GetPropertyAction("line.separator"));
```

Comment: +1, just beat me to it.  For reference, this can be derived from the `PrintWriter.newLine` call which simply defers to `out.write(lineSeparator)`.

Comment: Thank you! The line.separator property indeed was null. I caused it by calling System.setProperties( props ) with Properties object that contained only 4 properties for DBUnit. I wasn't aware that this method replaces all the properties. I should have read the javadoc more carefully. Again, thanks to both of you!

Comment: Super awesome.  Just spent hours trying to debug into the cause of this.  Same as you, someone had used the System.setProperties(props) method.